# How i can send a sms message (SOS) to a saved contact by shaking the phone - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, smsmanager, sos

I want to send an sms to all saved contact only by shaking the phone. But i don't know how to link the database of saved contact and the code of sendind sms. Please help me with that.
This is the code for sending an sms by shaking the phone :

public class SensorService extends Service {

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;

public SensorService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    // start the foreground service
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());

    // ShakeDetector initialization
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();
    mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onShake(int count) {
            // check if the user has shacked
            // the phone for 3 time in a row
            if (count == 3) {

                // vibrate the phone
                vibrate();

                // create FusedLocationProviderClient to get the user location
                FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());

    // register the listener
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

// method to vibrate the phone
public void vibrate() {

    final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    VibrationEffect vibEff;

    // Android Q and above have some predefined vibrating patterns
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        vibEff = VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_DOUBLE_CLICK);
        vibrator.cancel();
        vibrator.vibrate(vibEff);
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(500);
    }


}

// For Build versions higher than Android Oreo, we launch
// a foreground service in a different way. This is due to the newly
// implemented strict notification rules, which require us to identify
// our own notification channel in order to view them correctly.
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground() {
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("You are protected.")
            .setContentText("We are there for you")

            // this is important, otherwise the notification will show the way
            // you want i.e. it will show some default notification
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // create an Intent to call the Broadcast receiver
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, ReactivateService.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

And this is the code for saving contact number :

public void storeInDB(View v) {

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sauvegarde commencée",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    name = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    number = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String str_name=name.getText().toString();
    String str_number=number.getText().toString();
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("NumDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details(name VARCHAR,number VARCHAR);");

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM details", null);
    if(c.getCount()<3)
    {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO details VALUES('"+str_name+"','"+str_number+"');");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enregistré avec succès",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nombre maximum limité atteint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    db.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i dont' know if you can send SMS to a list of contacts.
If you read this documentation:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm
you'll read that the APIs receive MAX a telephone number.

I think this implementation is also due to a protection that android creates for avoiding to send a lot of sms togheter.

Assuming you have saved 1500 contacts on your device, your APP have to send 1500 sms???
It's strange....

But of couse you can create a loop and send a SMS a time...

I suggest you to:

1. detected shake gesture
2. retrieve all contacts saved (https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/06/how-to-get-contacts-in-android-display-into-listview.html)
3. send a sms a time.